# Using sdo_contains with transient object in Oracle

Tags: oracle, spatial-query, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

I have two varchar columns with wkt value (a polygon and a point). I want to know if there are a polygon that contains some point using Oracle.

I'm using sdo_contains command, but don't work. According the documentation, the polygon should be indexed. Can anyone help me how to get around this problem?
I don't want to create a geometry column. I can't change the table structure or add a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SDO_CONTAINS` is a spatial operator function and does indeed require an index (or rather, an indexed geometry column).

For arbitrary in-memory geometry objects, you can use `SDO_GEOM.RELATE` with the `CONTAINS` or `INSIDE` mask.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objgeom.htm#BGHCDIDG

Comment: Thanks @Ben. To future reference: `sdo_geom.relate(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(a.wkt_polygon, 4326), 'contains', sdo_geom.sdo_geometry('POINT(' || b.longitude || ' ' || b.latitude || ')', 4326), 0.005)`